# Why is JMS Serializer not returning the correct array keys upon deserialization?

Tags: php, arrays, annotations, deserialization, jms-serializer

I am using JMS annotations to serialize a PHP object upon persistence. One of the object's properties is an array of integers with integer keys. I used the following annotation as described in the [JMS Serializer documentation](https://jmsyst.com/libs/serializer/master/reference/annotations#postdeserialize):

```
/**
 * @var int[]
 *
 * @Serializer\Type("array<integer, integer>")
 */
private $intArrayWithIntKeys;
```

The array is persisted correctly as Json in the form:

```
{..., "int_array_with_int_keys":{"123":456}}
```

However, upon deserialization of the object the array key "123" is replaced with "0". Serialization and deserialization of all the other properties works fine, it is just this associative array that is not being deserialized correctly. Am I missing something? Is there some convenient way of preserving the array keys during the deserialization?

Comment: I have got this to work by using string keys of the form "string_123" instead of integer keys, and then converted back to an array with integer keys in PHP after deserialisation. This works, but I have not found a solution to the original problem posted.